# `rm -f` asks for confirmation, when aliased as `rm -i`

Tags: bash, alias, rm

I'm using this command to try and delete all Thumbs.db files in a very large folder. I thought `-f` should force deletion without asking for confirmation, but i'm still being prompted for "y" or "n" on every file.

```
find "megapacks" -name Thumbs.db -ok rm -f {} \;
```

I tried `type rm` to see if there was an alias and it responded with

> rm is aliased to `rm -i'

I tried using `/bin/rm` instead but i'm still being prompted

```
find "megapacks" -name Thumbs.db -ok /bin/rm -f {} \;
```

Does anyone have another idea for how to avoid the confirmation?

Comment: Use `-delete` instead?

Comment: Note that aliases are not expanded for arguments to commands, which is what `rm` would be here.

Comment: `unalias rm` before you lose all caution about pointing the gun at your foot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with `-ok` option that is as per `man find`:

> Like `-exec`  but **ask the user first**. If the user agrees, run the command.  Otherwise just return false.

This should work for you with `-exec`:

```
find "megapacks" -name Thumbs.db -exec /bin/rm -f {} \;
```

or faster:

```
find "megapacks" -name Thumbs.db -exec /bin/rm -f {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

But I think the problem is that you pass `-ok` to `find`, which is

> Like `-exec` but ask the user first.

If the alias were the problem, simply unset the alias:

```
unalias rm
```

Note that this only affect the current shell session.

You can also use the `-delete` option for `find`:

```
find "megapacks" -name Thumbs.db -delete
```